# iPhone + framework

Tags: iphone, frameworks

While including any new framework for an application, if we look into the path /Developer/Platforms, we get following two platform:

iPhoneOS.platform 
iPhoneSimulator.platform

In both the above folders we see almost the same frameworks.

So, my question is that which framework we should include from the anyone of the above.

Regards,
Pratik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the framework from iPhoneOS.platform folder.

Specifically, you have to go down to iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/(iPhoneOS3.0.sdk or iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk or whatever version you are using)/System/Library/Frameworks and select the framework from that Frameworks folder.